# What is the required caster level to make a Sunblade?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting

Per the magic item creation rules:

> Creating a magic weapon has a special prerequisite: The creator's caster level must be at least three times the enhancement bonus of the weapon. If an item has both an enhancement bonus and a special ability, the higher of the two caster level requirements must be met. A magic weapon must have at least a 1 enhancement bonus to have any melee or ranged special weapon abilities.

So what is the caster level requirement to create a Sun Blade?

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/sun-blade

Is it 6 (3 x its normal +2 enhancement bonus), 12 (3 x its +4 enhancement bonus when used vs evil) or something else keyed off one of its other properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When considering a weapon that has both an enhancement bonus and special abilities, the rules say

> the **higher** of the two caster level requirements must be met.

So the requirement for the +2 enhancement bonus is 3×2=6, as you noted. The requirement for its special properties (improved enhancement bonus against evil, double damage against undead/NEP things, sunlight thing) is CL 5th, usually, because they require *daylight*, a 3rd-level spell. Since 5th is not higher than 6th, though, it does not matter: the requirement is 6th, as it is the higher requirement.

Comment: Yeah, non-standard weapons don't have increased CL requirements, which makes them easy (if expensive) the create.